# child with 100% width in padding applied parent

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with this css specifications:

```
width:200px;
padding:5px
border:1px solid
```

and another `div` as it's child with this css:

```
width:100%
border:1px solid
```

and these divs has rendered in FF and IE like this:
[image]

But it seems the right padding is less than left one! can any one tell me why this behavior causes?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this happens because the borders of the inner `div` are not part of the definition of the `width` itself, so your inner div is actually `100% + 2px` wide.

you should specify `box-sizing: border-box;` for the inner div, so its width will include borders

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/box-sizing) for further information (and browser support) about this property.

Answer (score 5):

Its the border that pushes it to the right. set `box-sizing: border-box` to the inner div.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check the box model once again.

You are having a div with width 100% and adding border 1px to it, so the divs becomes 100% + 2px width and it's pushed to the right like you see.

You should drop the "width: 100%" and add just the border. (since the div is a block element it will take the full width)

You don't need to add box-sizing even, since IE7 won't support it. (if you want IE7 support)

Answer (score 0):

What is the overflow like on your parent element? Unless I am mistaken your setting the width to 100% with a border, so the width is 200px inside a div that is 200px and so the border will not show.

My quick solution (sure there is a better way) would be to make the padding on the right 2px more or left 2px less than the overall padding.

Comment: i used `overflow:hidden` for the parent, but no luck!!

Comment: @frogatto mix border-box with overflow hidden worked